# Removing only one element of the duplicate elements using collections in java

Tags: java, collections

I have to find all the duplicates and return them using collections. For example, if list = {1,1,2,2,2} it will return {1,2,2}. So in other words, the pattern is you return -1 of the number of duplicates.

Here is the method:

```
public static Integer[] returnDuplicate (Integer[] list ){
        // Insert your code here. You may want to change the return value. 
    
        return null 
}
```

```
public static Integer[] returnDuplicate (Integer[] list ){
        List<Integer> uniqueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
                  for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                       if (list[k] == list[j] && k != j && !uniqueList.contains(list[k])) {
                uniqueList.add(list[k]);
            }
                   }
        }
        Integer[] result = new Integer[uniqueList.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer val : uniqueList) {
            result[i++] = val;
        }
        return result;
        
}
```

This is my code but it's returning {1,2} instead of {1,2,2}

Answer (score 2):

Since you're allowed to use Collections, you can maintain a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html) of elements that have been already encountered (it would be more performant than maintain `List` because `contains()` check on a list performs iteration over the whole list under the hood which results in **O(n)** time complexity, meanwhile `HashSet` produces the result almost instantly in **O(1)**).

And while iterating offer you need to offer the next element to the Set, if the element gets rejected, i.e. method `Set.add()` returns `false`, would mean that it's a duplicate, and we can add it to the resulting list of duplicated values.

```
public static Integer[] returnDuplicates(Integer[] list){
    List<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer next: list) {
        if (!seen.add(next)) duplicates.add(next);
    }
    return duplicates.toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(returnDuplicates(new Integer[]{1, 1, 2, 2, 2})));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: The requirement is not clear in case a number is not duplicated but it is worth noting that with this solution also non-duplicates are filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 public static List<Integer> returnDuplicate (Integer[] list ){
            List<Integer> uniqueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int prev = -1;
            for(Integer el : list){
              if(el == prev && prev != -1)
                uniqueList.add(el);
              prev = el;
            }
    
            return uniqueList;
            
    }
```